# PHP Convert multiple text input to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have 3 text box html (codeigniter)

```
echo form_input('id',$data['id']);
echo form_input('price',$data['price']);
echo form_input('quantity',$data['quantity']);
```

and want to convert it to array before sending to another process, like

```
$items = [
        array(
            'id' => 'item1',
            'price' => 300,
            'quantity' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'item2',
            'price' => 100,
            'quantity' => 2
        )
    ];
```

How it is possible?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?The "other process" you mention, is it server-side or client-side? if it is server-side, you already have all data from the form (including input) in $_POST, if it is client-side you need to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with in a for loop

`$stack = array();
array_push($stack, array('id'=>'d','value1'=>'e', 'value2' =>'f'));
array_push($stack, array('id'=>'x','value1'=>'y', 'value2' =>'z'));
print_r($stack); //print array`

Answer (score 0):

Try in a loop like this:

controller.php

```
$data['input'] = array(
             array(
                   'id' => 'item1',
                   'price' => 300,
                   'quantity' => 1
             ),
             array(
                   'id' => 'item2',
                   'price' => 100,
                   'quantity' => 2
            )
        );
```

view.php

```
<form action="action" method="post">
    <?php foreach($input as $item): ?>
        <?= form_input($item)?><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```